# How to list the files with the same name but different modification date in two different folders on MAC OS?

Tags: macos, file, terminal, command-prompt

The folders contain another folders too and I want it to be recursive.

Comment: Have you tried anything already?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time today to do it all for you, but here are the rudiments of a technique:

```
find DIRECTORY1 -exec bash -c 'b=$(basename "$1"); m=$(stat -f "%m" "$1"); echo $m:$b:$1' _ {} \; >/tmp/a

find DIRECTORY2 -exec bash -c 'b=$(basename "$1"); m=$(stat -f "%m" "$1"); echo $m:$b:$1' _ {} \; >/tmp/b
```

That will get you two files - `/tmp/a` and `/tmp/b` that look like this, with the modification time, basename and full name of each file separated by colons:

```
1492590869:a.gif:/users/mark/tmp/a.gif
1492591676:a.pdf:/users/mark/tmp/a.pdf
1493118064:a.png:/users/mark/tmp/a.png
1492857356:b.png:/users/mark/tmp/b.png
```

Now parse those with `awk` telling it the separator is a colon:

```
awk -F: '
      FNR==NR {time[NR]=$1;base[NR]=$2;full[NR]=$3; next}
              {t=$1;b=$2;n=$3; if(n in time && t!=time[something] ... 

   ' /tmp/a /tmp/b
```

On the first pass, where `FNR==NR` pick up the fields of the first file, then on the second pass do your checks and printing.

Gotta dash, but hope it helps. No-one said answers have to be complete.